# How to test correctness of arguments sent to external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I've external API endpoint, let's say: `http://www.fake_me_hard.com/api`. I would like to make some calls to this from my app.
Endpoint accepts following structure as argument:

```
  {   
  :amount => amount, 
  :backurl => root_path,
  :language => locale,
  :orderid => order_id, 
  :pm => payment_method, 
  :accept_url => "/payment/success", 
  :exception_url  =>  "/payment/failure", 
 }
```

For collecting this hash is responsible method `EndpointRequestCollector.give_me_hash`.
How I should test if `give_me_hash` returns proper structure ?

I can use the same strategy for creating this structure in `specs` and `class` as well so:

```
class EndpointRequestsCollector
  def self.give_me_hash
    {
       #....collecting hash #1
    }
  end
end

describe EndpointRequestCollector do
  context '.give_me_hash' do
    it 'returns proper structure' do
      expect(described_class.give_me_hash).to eq(
        {
          #... collecting hash #2
        }
       )
    end
  end
end
```

...but it would be repeating the same code in 2 places, and won't test anything.

Do you know any good approach to this problem ?

Comment: I dont undersatnd your issue

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that i usually test my json api's:

If you just want to test the format, you can use `include` matcher:

```
    %w(my awesome keys).each do |expected_key|
      expect(described_class.give_me_hash.keys).to include(expected_key)
    end
```

By doing this, you have the guarantee that the formar is correct, until someone break you method.

If you want to test the returned values, you can use something like that:

```
   let(:correct_value) { 42 }

   it 'must have correct value' do 
     expect(described_class.give_me_hash[key]). to eq correct_value
   end
```

But i recomment you to separate this the logic to get the value to another method, and make another test just for it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
let(:args) {["amount", "backurl", "language", "orderid", "pm", "accept_url", "exception_url"]}
#...
it 'returns proper structure' do
  described_class.give_me_hash.each_key do |key|
    expect(key).to satisfy{|key| args.include?(key)}
  end
end
```